# deploying a symfony 4 application

Tags: symfony, deployment, hosting

I want to host my symfony 4 application online, I configure the appache server to redirect to the index.php file

When I go to the server address, here is my error
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in C:\wamp64\www\test\public\index.php on line 18

configuration virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.tld
ServerAlias www.domain.tld

DocumentRoot C:/wamp64/www/test/public
<Directory C:/wamp64/www/test/public>
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

the index.php file is the basic one generate by symfony
thanks

Comment: You need at least php 7.1.3 on the server.  You have an older version.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the php 7.1 syntax used in that file, symfony 4 only supports php7.1+

Here is a handy guide on how to install/upgrade https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/upgrading-php-7-0-to-7-1